# How to run nx dep-graph on specific projects only

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I am working on a system that is using a mono-repo structure. We are using Nx as a tool to manage the workspace. This workspace consists of several feature-projects that get loaded into a single portal application.

When using Nx, I would like to run a dep-graph analysis on only a single project to show its dependant libraries without showing unrelated projects.

Is this possible with the current nx cli?

I tried running `nx dep-graph my-project-name` but this still showed the output of the entire workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this functionality is not available for `nx dep-graph`. This functionality can also be useful for me, that's why I'm waiting for it. Maybe if more people report interest here https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1864 someone will do it :)

Thanks for reporting this problem

---

**UPDATE**

---

Now you can generate deph graph for single project. You can simply add `include` parameter:

`nx dep-graph --include=project-one`

If you want to see the dependencies of several projects:

`nx dep-graph --include=project-one,project-two`

You can also exclude projects you don't want to see:

`nx dep-graph --include=project-one,project-two --exclude=project-three`

[More about dep-graph you can read here](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/cli/dep-graph)